# Exclude and include a file from a CRX Maven Plugin build

Tags: maven, google-chrome-extension

As I am developing my Google Chrome Extension, I want to be able to build different versions for environments.

I am using [The CRX Maven Plugin](http://crx-maven-plugin.btmatthews.com/) to build my extension.

By default, I want the files under src/main/chrome to be my dev files, since I use Chrome's "Load unpacked extension..." to test locally.  The extension also makes remote calls, so each environment has a corresponding remote server.  I have externalised that in a conf.js file.  I was thinking of excluding the src/main/chrome/conf.js file from the maven build and including another conf.js that is outside of /src/main/chrome with the following config:

```
...
<configuration>
...
    <packagingExcludes>js/conf.js</packagingExcludes>
...
</configuration>
```

I can't see a temporary build directory, where I could drop a conf.js using some additional script.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The [CRX Maven Plugin](http://crx-maven-plugin.btmatthews.com) now supports file filtering.

Instead of having a different conf.js for each environment you can put the name/value pairs for the environment specific settings into a Java .properties file called conf_XXX.properties where XXX is the name that you are going to use to identify the target environment for the build.

The plugin can be configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.btmatthews.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>crx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <filters>
            <filter>etc/conf_${targetEnv}.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        ...
   </configuration>
```

You would use the -D option to set the target environment at build time.

```
mvn -DtargetEnv=XXX
```